# How do I declare a controller method for a named route in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am attempting to declare a method/function in my controller that responds to a numerically named route. When I load any page in the site I receive an error stating the controller method could not be found, meaning that Laravel won't even load the application do to some incorrect formatting. I searched for an answer with no luck.

Here is the route I'm attempting to access via my Math controller:

> students/academics/math/7-12

Here is the method declaration to look for the route:

> public function get712()

Which gives me the following error no matter what page I'm loading:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Router::get712()

I'm not sure how to name the function/method in my controller for a purely numeric routes since hyphen is not allowed and there is no upper/lowercase for numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not pass 7-12 as a variable to a method?

route:

```
students/academics/math/{number}
```

controller:

```
public function getMath($number)
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: I also have students/academics/math/k-6 so this would also work since I am naming my View the same as the route and could use the variable in the View::make() declaration. I was able to name the route get_7_12() and have it function as I was asking.

Comment: This is wildly inappropriate, but I wanted to apologize for that comment in the weird `$("div")` question - I did not mean it sarcastically at all; quite the opposite. I'm sorry I caused you grief and in future I'll remember to be clearer when making such comments.

Comment: @Pointy I apologize. I had just gotten berated for an hour by someone with 350k plus rep b/c I asked a question about a person's problem (one the person w/ 350k was not interested in answering)  b/c i asked the question in the answer box b/c I didn't have enough reputation at that time to comment properly. The very next question I answered was the one where our paths crossed in which case your comment read as being sarcastic. I thought it was the same situation over again, when all I was trying to do was help some one. Sorry about that.

Comment: @jmgibson OK cool, I felt bad because my comment was more terse than it could have been, but I was honestly serious about your answer being insightful :) Stackoverflow can get a little caustic sometimes but overall I find that it brings out good things in people.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered that Laravel used to use underscores in the method name instead of camelCase so after scouring Google with no luck I declared the method like this:

> public function get_7_12()

voila!